# Chemfig: multiple arrows from one molecule

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I would like to have several arrows going from one molecule (chemfig).
I managed left and right, but now I also want one going 90° down from the molecule in the middle. This is what I tried (ignore the spacing problems on the right side):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
excretion
\arrow{<-}[90]
APAP-sulf \arrow{<-[SULT][sulfation]}[0,1.3]
    \chemname{\chemfig{HO-[:30]*6(-=-(-NH-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30])=-=)}}{Acetaminophen}
    \arrow{->[UGT][glucorination]}[0,1.3]APAP-gluc
    \arrow {->}[-90] excretion
    \arrow{->}[-90] NAPQI       
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I am not sure I understand the question, the code already produces vertical arrows on the left and right. What precisely do you want to achieve? An additional, vertical arrow from the molecule in the middle? If so, where precisely is it supposed to start and end?

Comment: There is one arrow, at the left side going down pointing at the word "NAPQI". this arrow is supposed to originate from the molecule in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal. Please make sure that you have updated your TeX distribution when you run it because it relies on some recent updates of the `tikzmark` library. You can remember

1. elements of a chemfig with the `@{<name>}{<element>}` syntax and
2. other things with the `\tikzmarknode{<name>}{<object>}` syntax.

And then you can use an `overlay` Ti*k*Z picture to draw arrows and whatever. I used the `calc` library to determine a possibly suitable starting point of the arrow. If you drop `blue` in the `\draw` command, the arrow will be black.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
excretion
\arrow{<-}[90]
APAP-sulf \arrow{<-[SULT][sulfation]}[0,1.3]
\chemname{\chemfig{@{HO}{HO}-[:30]*6(-=-(-NH-[:-30](=[:-90]@{O}{O})-[:30])=-=)}}{Acetaminophen}
    \arrow{->[UGT][glucorination]}[0,1.3]APAP-gluc
    \arrow {->}[-90] excretion
    \arrow{->}[-90] \tikzmarknode{NAPQI}{NAPQI}
\schemestop
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,-latex] ($(O)!0.1!(HO)-(0,0.5)$) -- (NAPQI.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a second proposal with a vertical arrow. If you want to restore the arrow from `excretion`, just remove `opacity=0`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
excretion
\arrow{<-}[90]
APAP-sulf \arrow{<-[SULT][sulfation]}[0,1.3]
\chemname{\chemfig{@{HO}{HO}-[:30]*6(-=-(-NH-[:-30](=[:-90]@{O}{O})-[:30])=-=)}}{
\tikzmarknode{A}{Acetaminophen}}
\arrow{->[UGT][glucorination]}[0,1.3]APAP-gluc
\arrow {->}[-90] excretion
\arrow{->}[-165,3,opacity=0] \tikzmarknode{NAPQI}{NAPQI}
\schemestop
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex,shorten >=4pt,shorten <=2pt] (A) -- (NAPQI);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version that does not rely on `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
excretion
\arrow{<-}[90]
APAP-sulf \arrow{<-[SULT][sulfation]}[0,1.3]
\chemname{\chemfig{@{HO}{HO}-[:30]*6(-=-(-NH-[:-30](=[:-90]@{O}{O})-[:30])=-=)}}{
Acetaminophen}
\arrow{->[UGT][glucorination]}[0,1.3]APAP-gluc
\arrow {->}[-90] excretion
\arrow{->}[-165,3,opacity=0] NAPQI
\arrow{<-}[90]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for you suggestion. How would I also place the NAPQI in the middle then? it is on the side just by accident and just supposed to be right under the middle molecule...

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell Do you want to connect it to `excretion` by an arrow or not?

Comment: No, I am sorry I put it a little unclear. I want a vertical arrow, down from the middle molecule and then the word NAPQI underneath

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell I made an update...

Comment: nice thanks! I am currently updating my tex distribution. It didn't work and I am pretty sure I don't have the updated version :D 
Stupid question, but since I've never updated before: If I update now, can I just use my script that I already have an compile it again, and then it will be compiled with the newest version?

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell Yes, in 99.99% of the cases an update won't make originally running scripts non-running. There are very rare exceptions, and if you run into one of them, it is quite likely that they will be almost instantly fixed if you bring them up (as a separate question) on this site. If you don't update, it is foreseeable that you will, sooner or later, run into problems.

Comment: Hey, so I've installed the newest version now and set it as default. But now when I try your suggestion, it will compile forever and when I stop it, it tells me the tikzmarknode is an "undefined control sequence"
what am I missing here? Is there a package I forgot?

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell I have no idea why this happens on your machine/installation but I added a version that does not rely on `tikzmark`. Which TeX installation do you use?

Comment: I am using: Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
the version which avoids tikzmark also compiles forever... If I now stop the compiling, it doesn't give error messages any more though...But still it doesn't want to do it :(

Comment: it does do the job, in a minimal example if I just compile, what you suggested... if I copy it to my script, it compiles forever...

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell But this version is only marginally different from yours. Any chance that you forgot to also copy `\end{document}`?

Comment: No, I have a master file with begin document and end document etc. I didn't change anything there, I just inserted this scheme in one of the sections :/

Comment: Does my document by itself on your machine? If the answer is yes, I'm afraid that you are not copying the thing correctly, or there are some macros or definitions in you main document at work which cause this. If the answer is no, then I am afraid that there is something wrong with your TeX installation, In either case, I can't say much since I neither know your TeX installation nor your large embedding file.

Comment: yes, your file does it. And my file only does the image without the arrow i am missing -.- I will now make a screenshot from the picture your file created and insert it as an image

Comment: found the mistake. It doesn't work in a two column environment even if I change to one column before I start the scheme

Comment: I have another question... Maybe you could explain to me, how you solved the first question, so that I can apply that to the new question below?

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell Please ask a new question. Asking questions is free. And please use the answer field only for an answer. And if my answer here solved your original question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it.