# How can I curve the line around a molecule in chemfig and add a floating line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

So I want to make my chemical formulars in TikZ and I have this right now:

[image]

My problem is that I want to curve the yellow line below the molecule to make the text more visible and to not cut the molecule in the middle. I've read through the chemfig manual already and found the Curved bonds, but I don't quite understand the syntax and how to add another control point.

My other problem is that I want to add a floating text with a floating arrow that points to a specific atom.

At the end I want it to kinda look like this: (I have added another orange and purple line to show what kind of lines I want)

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemfig{debug=false}
\setchemfig{scheme debug=false}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
        \subscheme{
            \chemfig{([::+90]C(-[::+135]H)(-[::+225]H)=C(-[::+45]H)(-[::+315]H))}
        }
        \+
        \chemfig{\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br}-\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br}}
        \arrow(.east--.west){<=>}
        \subscheme{
            \chemfig{([::+90]C(-[::+135]H)(-[::+225]H)=[@{a}]C(-[::+45]H)(-[::+315]H))}
        }
        \chemfig{@{b}\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[red,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^+$}{Br}-[@{c}]@{d}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|,45[blue,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^-$}{Br}}
        \arrow(@c2--)[-90]
        \chemfig{([::-90]C(-[::+90]H)(-[::+180]H)(-[::+270]\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br})-C(-[::+0]H)(-[::+90]\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br})(-[::+270]H))}
        \arrow(@c4--){<=>}[-90]
        \hflipnext
        \chemfig{\charge{180[red,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\oplus$}{Br}(-[1,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]@{e}C?(-[::+0]H)(-[::+90]H))(-[7,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]C?(-[::+0]H)(-[::+270]H))}
        \quad
        \quad
        \chemfig{@{f}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[blue,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\ominus$}{Br}}
        \arrow(@c5.0--@c6.183){<=>}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten >=4pt] (a).. controls +(0:1cm) and +(225:1cm).. (b);
        \draw[red,shorten >=4pt] (c).. controls +(270:1cm) and +(270:1cm).. (d);
        \draw[orange,shorten >=4pt] (f).. controls +(255:1cm) and +(225:1cm).. node[below] {Rueckseitenangriff} (e);
    }
\end{document}
```

Help would be appreaciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: duplicate ?? --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558650/place-a-tikz-node-on-an-arrow-in-a-chemfig-reaction-scheme/558655#558655

Comment: @jsbibra, not really, as the OP needs adding more points along the path. `to[out=,in=]` is of course one alternative to using `controls`, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options, and there's at least one more.

`chemfig` is built on `Tikz`, so you can use Tikz-commands, too. Which you did by

- giving certain coordinates names `(a) .. (f)`
- providing `\draw` pathes

Using `controls` is a way to specify Bezier curves in Tikz. I find the parameters hard to imagine, though if you can, it's a perfect way to create fancy curves.

However, I provide two alternatives:

```
        % ~~~ straight forward replacement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[orange,shorten >=4pt] 
                    (f) -- ++(0,-1.7) 
                        -- node[pos=.5,below]{Rückseitenangriff} ++(-3.5,0)
                        --  (e);
```

- `\draw` from (f) -- (e)
- but before ending this path by `;`
- place two new coordinates (`++`) for the down- and side-steps, described as relative steps
- put a `node` at the lower new path (watch the missing `\`) // use `pos=` for furter fine tuning
- no fancy curving, just draw as specified

```
        % ~~~ an alternative ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[green,shorten >=4pt,rounded corners] 
                    (f.230) -- ++(0,-1.5) 
                        --  ++(-3.2,0)
                        --  (e);
```

- same idea
- left out the `node`, as the drawing won't expand for some reason
- used `rounded corners` option from `Tikz`
- shifted the starting point a bit to the left, using polar coordinates `(f.230)`

You could also replace all or some of the `--` statements by `to[in=,out=]`, like so:

```
(f.230) to[out=300,in=45] ++(0,-1.5) ...
```

to start with a bow (hopefully) to the right.

As you can also see I put the language package `babel` for convenience.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % <<<
\usepackage{chemfig}

%\setchemfig{debug=false}
%\setchemfig{scheme debug=false}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
        \subscheme{
            \chemfig{([::+90]C(-[::+135]H)(-[::+225]H)=C(-[::+45]H)(-[::+315]H))}
        }
        \+
        \chemfig{\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br}-\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br}}
        \arrow(.east--.west){<=>}
        \subscheme{
            \chemfig{([::+90]C(-[::+135]H)(-[::+225]H)=[@{a}]C(-[::+45]H)(-[::+315]H))}
        }
        \chemfig{@{b}\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[red,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^+$}{Br}-[@{c}]@{d}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|,45[blue,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^-$}{Br}}
        \arrow(@c2--)[-90]
        \chemfig{([::-90]C(-[::+90]H)(-[::+180]H)(-[::+270]\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br})-C(-[::+0]H)(-[::+90]\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br})(-[::+270]H))}
        \arrow(@c4--){<=>}[-90]
        \hflipnext
        \chemfig{\charge{180[red,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\oplus$}{Br}(-[1,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]@{e}C?(-[::+0]H)(-[::+90]H))(-[7,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]C?(-[::+0]H)(-[::+270]H))}
        \quad
        \quad
        \chemfig{@{f}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[blue,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\ominus$}{Br}}
        \arrow(@c5.0--@c6.183){<=>}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[red,shorten >=4pt] (a).. controls +(0:1cm) and +(225:1cm).. (b);
        \draw[red,shorten >=4pt] (c).. controls +(270:1cm) and +(270:1cm).. (d);
%        \draw[orange,shorten >=4pt] (f).. controls +(255:1cm) and +(225:1cm).. node[below] {Rueckseitenangriff} (e);
        % ~~~ straight forward replacement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[orange,shorten >=4pt] 
                    (f) -- ++(0,-1.7) 
                        -- node[pos=.5,below]{Rückseitenangriff} ++(-3.5,0)
                        --  (e);
        % ~~~ an alternative ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[green,shorten >=4pt,rounded corners] 
                    (f.230) -- ++(0,-1.5) 
                        --  ++(-3.2,0)
                        --  (e);
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach

```
\documentclass[border={5mm 12mm 5mm 5mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\tikzset{mybond/.style={dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt}}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)=[2]C(-[1]H)(-[3]H)}
\arrow{0}[,0]
\+
\chemfig{\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br}-\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br}}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemfig{C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)=[@{a}2]C(-[1]H)(-[3]H)}
\arrow{0}[,0.2]
\chemfig{@{b}\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[red,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^+$}{Br}-[@{c}]@{d}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|,45[blue,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\delta^-$}{Br}}
\arrow(@c3--){<=>}[-90]
\arrow(@c1--)[-90]
\chemfig{H-[2]C(-\charge{0=\|,90=\|,270=\|}{Br})(-[4]H)-[2]C(-H)(-[4]\charge{90=\|,180=\|,270=\|}{Br})-[2]H}
\arrow{<=>}[,2.03]
\chemfig{C?[db1](-[5]H)(-[7]H)(-[2,0.75,,,draw=none]-[,0.8,,,draw=none]@{g}\charge{180[red,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\oplus$}{Br}?[db1,,mybond]?[db2]-[,,,,draw=none]@{f}\charge{0=\|,90=\|,180=\|,270=\|,45[blue,circle,anchor=180+\chargeangle]=$\ominus$}{Br})-[2,1.5]@{e}C?[db2,,mybond](-[1]H)(-[3]H)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{%
    \draw[red, shorten >=4pt] (a) .. controls +(0:8mm) and +(225:12mm).. (b);
    \draw[red, shorten >=4pt] (c) .. controls +(270:1cm) and +(270:1cm).. (d);
    \draw[orange, shorten >=4pt, shorten <=4pt] (f) .. controls +(255:3.5cm) and +(225:4cm).. (e) node[pos=0.35, below=1pt] {Rueckseitenangriff};
    \draw[<-, shorten <=4pt, blue] (g) -- ++(60:1) node[above] {Text};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]